# How many partitions of natural numbers into composite numbers are there?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory, generating-functions

In a [graph-theoretic context](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057871/graph-puzzles-constructing-graphs-from-tiles) the following question arose:

> Given a natural number $n$. In how many ways can it be written as
> the sum of composite numbers?

As an example, the number $64$ can be written as $60+4$ , $58+6$ , $56+8$ , $56+4+4$ , $54+10$ , $54+6+4$ , $\dots$ , $32+32$, $32+28+4$,$\dots$

The graph-theoretic background of this question was the following. The vertex-induced subgraph

[image]

may appear 64 times in a graph with 64 vertices. There are many random graphs with this property, but some graphs are sets of disjoint torified rectangular square grids. (Torified means that opposite vertices on the sides of a rectangular square grid are connected.) For example two torified square grids with 4x8 vertices each, or four torified square grids with 2x4 vertices each. So the number of such multiple torus graphs is the number I am looking for (for $64$).

In other words: I am looking for the composite [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) of natural numbers.

---

Thanks to player3236's hint now I know the answer for $64$: it is [$2357$](https://oeis.org/A023895/b023895.txt). But it would be great to know the number of *all* graphs with the above property. I assume this will be a really big number, but it might be impressive to see exactly *how* small the fraction of regular graphs with this property is, and that it will tend to 0 for really large graphs. Is there a way to estimate it? But I admit, this is another question.

Comment: Just to clarify : Is $1$ excluded as well ? I ask because $1$ is also a non-prime. If so, "composite" would be a better name.

Comment: Something like https://oeis.org/A023895: Number of partitions of n into composite parts, or https://oeis.org/A002095: Number of partitions of n into nonprime parts?

Comment: @player3236: That's it. Now the generating function (or whatever) would be interesting.

Comment: @bof: You are right, the restriction is not necessary. Being not composite itself just reduces the partition number by 1.

Comment: Notably, the second of the OEIS links includes the G.F.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Please help me, I cannot see it.

Comment: It's on the A002095 entry under Formula: "G.f.: Product_{i>0} (1-x^prime(i))/(1-x^i)".

Comment: @Semiclassical: So easy. But this can also be found in the A023895 entry: "G.f.: (1-x)*Product_{j>=1} (1-x^prime(j))/(1-x^j)"